# Report Date Selection Issue

Tags: date, ms-access

I am having a really annoying issue and cannot see what I have done wrong. I have a number of reports on my database which are filtered by a date range. The date range is set in a simple **reports index** form with a `[start date]` and an `[end date]` which are both unbound fields which are set manually using a calendar dropdown.

All but one of the reports works fine having set a parameter value in the reports query builder using the perameter `Between [forms]![reports index]![start date] And [forms]![reports index]![End Date]`

I have one report though for which this parameter value seems to be inoperative such that the report pulls all records in regardless of date and regardless of this parameter being present. I removed the field from the query builder and opened the report which asked for the date parameter. Having entered a date the report simply pulled in all of the records regardless of date and put the date I just entered into all the records...

I noticed that the date in the form was in short date format and in the record it was a long date so I have adjusted this and set a input mask so date entry is now uniform but I don't think this had anything to do with it. The date is set in most of the forms by a simple on open parameter that sets the date of that record to `Date()` or by manual entry from the calendar dropdown.

Do you need more info a better explanation...? Please help as I have to have the report sorted and dealt with and ready to print on Monday and am lost for an answer as I cannot see I have done anything differently to the other reports which all work fine.

Comment: Please share the SQL version of the query on which the report is based.

Comment: sorry I see what you mean. Its not the SQL its the query builder within access.

Comment: please follow the steps outlined here to view the SQL statement for the query. https://www.techonthenet.com/access/queries/view_sql2007.php

Comment: Sounds like a date parameter is on the Field row in the query builder. Switch to SQLView to see SQL statement. Copy/paste it into your question.

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks for the replies. I have managed to sort it out now. It was a completely silly and embarrassing school boy error. I had forgotten that I was working on a split data base. Whilst I set the data type in the front end form to be a date it was set in the remote table as a text field. I thought I had reset this but as I was working on my local front end any changes I made or thought I'd made to the table were not carried through to the back end tables... Annoyingly, no error message flagged this up but hey ho... I realised my error when I noticed no calendar drop down and I noticed two different date formats had been entered by users. Anyway, having changed the table in the remote back end I have now got a working report. Thanks once again. I will no doubt have more questions soon.